# access message queue SQL Server from nodejs

Tags: sql, sql-server, node.js, queue, msmq

I'm writing a webAPI in nodejs. I want to expose a socket.io to clients so they can get realtime notifications. The information I want to send to the clients is stored on a SQL Server 2008 R2 database. I'm clear on how to send the data from nodejs to the clients... what I can't figure out is **how to send the notification from SQL Server to nodejs?**

There seems to be a possible solution using a new [service bus module](http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/04/node-socketio-servicebus) from Microsoft but installing and managing a service bus looks like asking for trouble.

I read about a lot of MQ solutions for nodejs like `node_redis`, `node_stomp`, etc. but none of they speak directly with MSMQ or SQL Server.

I'm a total newbie on the MQ world, but I guess I'll manage to put the data I need from SQL Server to a MSMQ queue, so my question is, **how can I access a MSMQ queue from nodejs?**

Thanks.-

Comment: If you want to use the publish/subscribe model for your notifications, then a service bus is exactly what you want. Why do you think it 'looks like asking for trouble'?

Comment: because I just wanted to send a message from SQL to node... "service bus" seems totally overkill. I ended up creating a 10 lines c# code to send a TCP message, complided into an assembly and registered it onto SQL Server. A quick test and I was able to send 10000 messages from SQL to nodejs in less than a second... (actual load will be about 500 messages per second), so I'm pretty happy with it.

Comment: @Nick can you share your 10 lines of code please ?

Comment: @Eng-AymanAbdulhamidElarian agreed! Nick please answer your question, I could use this code too